# Can't convert dictionary to the array. Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

Well, I am totally confused. I am trying to get the array of keys from the dictionary. This is what I wrote:

```
if (customerViewModel.customer._dynamicMonthCount != nil) {
    var array = customerViewModel.customer._dynamicMonthCount
    var months_keys = Array(arrayLiteral: array!.keys) //that does not work
}
```

Well, as you understood, "_dynamicMonthCount" is a dictionary:

```
var _dynamicMonthCount:Dictionary<String,Int>?
```

I give it the value as I get the data from server in json. (Actually, that dictionary is JSON Object as Dictionary).

BUT, every time I debug the program, I see that array is [LazyMapCollection<[String : Int], String>].

I tried that with different array and it works :

```
let dictionary = var regions:Dictionary<String,Int> = [...]  //my static dictionary
var values = Array(dictionary.values) //that works 
var keys = Array(dictionary.keys) //that works
```

Does that mean that the only problem in optional type and dynamic data? I don't know, help me, guys, please

Comment: A variable `array` for a *dictionary* is very confusing. Consider also that (almost) all *variables* in your code are supposed to be constants (`let`)

Comment: You should never have to use the `Array(arrayLiteral:)` initialiser directly (it's meant for the compiler to use when working with array literals) – just use the `Array(_:)` initialiser instead... like you do in your second example!

Comment: What you you mean with `that does not work`? Does it crash? Does it fail to compile? Does it show an empty array?

Comment: You should also use [Optional Binding](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330) to unwrap your dictionary, rather than a `!= nil` check followed by a force unwrap.

Comment: Array(_:) - works. That converts dictionary.keys to array. I used "arrayLiteral" because of the warning. But it was bad idea. Thank you for your comments!

Comment: @LisaSemyonova If you think an answer answers your question, please consider accepting by clicking on that checkmark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just delete the `arrayLiteral:` thing and it will work!

```
var months_keys = Array(array!.keys) //that does not work
```

The `arrayLiteral` initializer should be used like this:

```
var month_keys = Array(arrayLiteral: 1, 2, 3, 4) 
// will produce an array with items: 1, 2, 3 and 4
```

What you should call instead is the `(_: SequenceType)` initializer, since `LazyMapCollection<[String : Int], String>` conforms to that protocol.

A few more tips for your code:

- If a variable's value is not going to change, declare it with `let`, instead of `var`.
- You can simplify this:

-

```
if (customerViewModel.customer._dynamicMonthCount != nil) {
    var array = customerViewModel.customer._dynamicMonthCount
    var months_keys = Array(array!.keys)
}
```

to this:

```
if let dictionary = customerViewModel.customer._dynamicMonthCount {
    var months_keys = Array(dictionay!.keys)
}
```